# How does tensorflow.GradientTape() accumulate operation within a loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow, so this may be a dummy question. I'm trying to figure out what tf.GradientTape() is doing, and I couldn't quite understand how it's recording the operations. Here's the code I tried:

```
mean = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
xs = tf.constant([2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
for x in xs:
  with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    y = x * x
  print(y, mean(y))
```

Abd here's the output:

```
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(6.5, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(16.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(9.666667, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

It looks like the mean operation gets accumulated across loops, where in loop 1, it computes 4/1 = 4; in loop 2, it computes (4+9)/2=6.5, and in loop 3, it computes (4+9+16)/3 = 9.666667. But what puzzles me is that the square operation (*x* * *x*) isn't accumulated, because when *y* is printed out at each loop, it's just *y*, and yet when I take the mean of *y*, it becomes the mean of *y* + all previous *y*'s.

I can sort of imagine this to be useful when computing loss, as we can easily take the mean of accumulated loss over samples/batches. But i have trouble visualize how tf.GradientTape is "selectively" recording operations behind the scene.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the gradient tape, in fact the gradient tape here doesn't do anything. All [`Metric`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric) types in Keras (like `Mean`) work cumulatively, with the idea that you can get the value of a metric for a whole epoch that is divided in multiple batches. You can always call `reset_states` to reset the metric computation (if you are using metrics manually, you would call this after each epoch or batch, depending on what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mean(lst):
  return tf.reduce_mean(lst)
  
xs = tf.constant([2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
for x in xs:
  with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    y = x * x
  print(y, mean(y))
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(16.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(16.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

As i have used reduce_mean() it only calculates mean of the tensor at that instance but, tf.keras.metrics.mean() accumulates every time its compiled. Hope, this cleared out your doubt.

```
mean = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
xs = tf.constant([2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
for i in range(0,2):
  for x in xs:
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
      y = x * x
    print(y, mean(y))
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(6.5, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(16.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(9.666667, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(8.25, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(8.4, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(16.0, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(9.666667, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_gradient(x):
   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      y = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
   gradient = tape.gradient(y, x)
   return gradient, y
        
test = tf.Variable([0.5, 0.6, 0.7])
gradient, y = get_gradient(test)
```

Let's consider a sigmoid activation function. A sigmoid activation function outputs values from 0 to 1.

g(x) = 1/(1 + e^(-x)) = y

g'(x) = g(x)(1 - g(x))

Example: Let, x = 0.5

g(0.5) = 1/(1 + e^(-0.5)) = 0.62245

g'(0.5) = g(x)(1 - g(x)) = 0.2350

########################################################################

**with tf.GradientTape() as tape:** within this you defined your function you wanted to differentiate. Here, it is y = sigmoid(x). Tape will record all the operations on x.

**gradient = tape.gradient(y, x)** y = f(x) is a function with y' = f'(x). Input parameters are tensor of y (solved at given x) and x. It returns dy/dx as a tensor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think directly solved my confusion. I have no problem understanding your example, as I'm not confused about the steps of codes that I need to enter to compute a gradient, I was mainly confused about how this GradientTape function is recording or accumulating operations behind the scene, especially with regard to the codes/example I gave in the question.

Comment: mean.reset_states() clears the accumulation. It is not about the gradient tape what is accumulating the values its tf.keras.metrics.Mean(). This is the reason why we reset states of mean for every epoch during training.